# Change in Enthalpy in Free Expansion of Ideal and Real gas against Vacuum

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy, kinetic-theory-of-gases

By free expansion, I am referring to gas allowed to expand freely against vacuum in a Joule Expansion.

If gas is ideal then change in Internal Energy '∆U' and change in Enthalpy '∆H' is zero.
(By ∆H = ∆U + nR∆T).

But I was wondering whether '∆H' would still be zero for real gas?

(I know that ∆U will be zero for real gas. I just want to ask about ∆H)

Comment: I know about ∆U. I want to know about ∆H.

Comment: I didn't understand your point. ∆H = ∆U + nR∆T is just applicable to ideal gases, right?

Comment: So how do I know about ∆H? (for real gas)

Comment: See [Joule-Thomson effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect)  for real gas vacuum expansion and [van der Waals equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waals_equation) for pV=f(T,p) dependence. As $\Delta H=\Delta U + f(T,p)$. Also look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule_expansion

Comment: @Poutnik Joule Thomson effect is a bit different from this as it has constant H but not constant U. Joule expansion is exactly what I am talking about, but its wiki page has nothing on H only U. I had asked this question after reading that only

Comment: That's why I asked only about H and not U.

Comment: @InfiniteCool23  It doesn't sound like you are asking about a free expansion, since it's **not** generally the case that $\Delta \text{U} =0$ for free expansions of real gases.  Instead, it sounds like you are asking about an *adiabatic* free expansion, i.e., a *Joule* expansion.  If that's the case, you should edit your question appropriately.

Comment: @InfiniteCool23 "Technically, it would be called adiabatic only if q=constant throughout the process." Nope.  q is a path variable.  You're incorrectly treating it like a state variable. Initial and final states don't "have heat" the way they have, e.g., internal energy.  q only appears during a process.  And adiabatic doesn't mean q is constant.  It means q is zero (no heat flow) for the process.

Comment: @InfiniteCool23  "I think that ΔU=0 is generally the case for free expansion"  Nope.   If you have a free expansion, w=0 but, if it's not adiabatic, q will generally not be zero for real gases.

Comment: I am just talking about Joule expansion, then what will be change in enthalpy for real gas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Joule expansion, which is an irreversible *adiabatic* expansion against a vacuum, $q = 0 \text{ and } p_{ext} = 0$.  Thus, since the only type of work in a Joule expansion is $pV$-work:

$$\Delta \text{U} = q + w = w = -p_{ext} \Delta V = 0 \text{,  always.}$$

And since $\Delta \text{H} = \Delta \text{U}+ \Delta pV$:

$$\Delta \text{H} = \Delta pV \text {, always.}$$

For ideal gases:

$pV$ = constant (at a given $T$), so $\Delta \text{H} = \Delta pV = 0.$

For real gases, we have two cases:

I. At the inversion temperature:

$pV = \text{constant (at a given } T \text{), so } \Delta \text{H} = \Delta pV = 0$.

II. Not at the inversion temperature:

$pV \ne \text{constant, so } \Delta \text{H} = \Delta pV \ne 0$.

Answer (score 1):

In the Joule experiment, $\Delta H$ is not zero for a real gas.  $\Delta H=\Delta U+\Delta (PV)$, and even if $\Delta U$ is zero, there is no physical reason to expect that $\Delta (PV)$ would be zero in this process.